# error: expected initializer before '*' token

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, syntax-error

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int** add(int** first, int** second);
int addAllElems(int** matrix);
int addAllElems(int** matrix);
void display(int** matrix);

int main()
{
    int first** = {{5,7,4}, {3,9,2}, {7,3,6}};
    int second** = {{3,7,2}, {6,2,6}, {3,5,8}};

    cout << "The first matrix is:" << endl;
    display(first);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "The second matrix is:" << endl;
    display(second);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "The sum of the two matrices is:" << endl;
    display(add(first, second));
    cout << endl;

    cout << "The sum of all elements of the first matrix is: "
        << addAllElems(first) << endl;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

int** add(int** first, int** second) {
    int[][] sum = new int[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
            sum[i][j] = first[i][j] + second[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int addAllElems(int** matrix) {
    int sumOfElems = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
            sumOfElems += matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sumOfElems;
}

void display(int** matrix) {
    cout << "[" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << ", ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;
}
```

Who can fix this code?

I'm getting this error when compiling it:

```
 In function 'int main()':
12:14: error: expected initializer before '*' token
63:1: error: expected '}' at end of input
```

I think the problem is from my array declaration.
I think the problem is from my array declaration.
I think the problem is from my array declaration.
I think the problem is from my array declaration.

Comment: Pointers to pointers are not 2D arrays.

Comment: @Inyavic Sage  This declaration and initialization int first** = {{5,7,4}, {3,9,2}, {7,3,6}}; (I think you mean int ** first instead of int first ** ) are incorrect. A scalar object may be initialized with a braced list with only one initializer.

Answer (score 0):

First the stars need to be directly to the right of a type:

```
int** first;
```

Then you need to initialize it differently:

```
int** first = new int*[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        first[i] = new int[3];
    }
    first[0][0] = 5;
    first[0][7] = 7;
    // ...
```